# Mallelt training dataset with any class specified in Mallet API

Tags: training-data, mallet

I have a dataset with 15000 words with comma separated values , I want train mallet so that whenever we do a tag extraction further we should get result keeping trained data set in mallet .

I need some sample piece of code to train my dta using programmticlly pls help in this.

Comment: which class is best suited for Data set training